# Smooth map between $\mathbb C^n$ and $\mathbb C$ and regular level set theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm hoping someone can tell me where I am slipping up:

Let $f: \mathbb C^n \rightarrow \mathbb C$ be a smooth (and holomorphic) map and suppose $0 \in \textrm{Image}( f)$, and further that $0$ is a regular value for $f$, i.e., $df$ is surjective at every point in $f^{-1}(0)$. So at least one of the partial derivatives of $f$ is non-zero at every point in $f^{-1}(0)$, taken with respect to the $2n$ coordinates $x_i$, $y_i$, $i = 1,\dots n$.

Then, by the Regular Level Set Theorem, $f^{-1}(0)$ is a smooth submanifold of codimension 2 i.e., a manifold of dimension $2n-2$ sitting in $\mathbb C^n$.

So far so good...I think.

Now let $\hat f:\mathbb C^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be the smooth map defined by taking the real part of $f$, $$\hat f(z)= \Re\left[f(z)\right].$$ Projection is smooth, so this is smooth since $f$ is smooth.

We also have that $0 \in $ Image$(\hat f)$. Again, to say that $0$ is a regular value in this case, we need the diferential, $d\hat f$ to be surjective at every point in the pre-image of $0$, and thus need that at least one of the partial derivatives of $\hat f$ to be non-zero with respect to the $2n$ coordinates $x_i$, $y_i$, $i = 1,\dots n$.

Since $f$ is holomorphic, $0$ being a regular value for $f$ implies that $0$ is a regular value for $\hat f$.

Finally, applying the Regular Level Set Theorem to $\hat f$ we get that $\hat f^{-1}(0)$ is submanifold of dimension $2n-1$. However, $\hat f ^{-1}(0) = f^{-1}(0)$!

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Why is $\hat f^{-1}(0) = f^{-1}(0)$? Are you claiming $f$ never takes on purely imaginary values?

Comment: Ohh right! No, I am definitely not claiming that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done great up until your *very last line*: there's no reason to believe that $\hat f^{-1}(0) = f^{-1}(0)$. Indeed, if $f$ is holomorphic, that's not possible (Picard's theorem applied to some line $\Bbb C \subset \Bbb C^n$ implies that $f$ takes on all but at most one value, so in particular must be somewhere purely imaginary; that has $f(x) \neq 0$ but $\hat f(x) = 0$).

There's no contradiction in what you've done before; $f^{-1}(0) \subset \hat f^{-1}(0)$, each being submanifolds of the appropriate dimension.